# Styling Radio Buttons/Checkboxes in Rails 4+

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to the Rails environment and am trying to change the color of one of my labels (to white) attached to a check box.
I am using inline CSS here:

```
<style>
.new_labels{
color: #FFFFFF;
}
</style>
```

with the following Ruby code:

```
<%= f.check_box :remember_me %>
<%= f.label :remember_me, "Remember Me", :class => "new_labels" %>
```

However, this doesn't do anything, and I've tried numerous other solutions with no success.

EDIT: it works fine when the label isn't attached to a check box or radio button (such as text_field or email_field). But I need to change the color of these labels to fit my color scheme for my app.

Comment: Are you using internal css?

Comment: @claudios Yes, as denoted by the first code block

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap or something that might be overriding your internal style sheet (post `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` and `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css`)? What happens when you move your styling to an external style sheet in your `stylesheets` directory?

Comment: @MarsAtomic it remains unchanged even when I try that.

Comment: Bear in mind that the Rails asset pipeline actually looks for resources in three different directories. Double check and make sure you don't have anything in `app/lib/assets` or `app/vendor/assets` that might be stomping on your changes.

Comment: @MarsAtomic I just checked both and I have a .keep file in both, which is empty.